# Playstation Plus: Buy game from "Instant Game Collection"?

Tags: ps3, psn

I'm a new subscriber of Playstation Plus and I've downloaded a few games in the "Instant Game Collection" that are offered free right now to subscribers. I know that I can play these games as long as I maintain a valid Playstation Plus subscription.

However, what if I want to really **purchase** one of these games digitally (not on disc) so that I can play it even after my Playstation Plus subscription expires? I do not want to wait till my subscription expires to purchase one of these "free" games because there may be some good deals in between to buy these at a cheaper price (instead of looking for a good price after the subscription expires).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. I'm looking at how I can permanently "own" a game that's free for Playstation Plus users while the subscription is still active. I've already read all the FAQs on Playstation Plus, which is what the answer to that question quotes.

Comment: Purchase it.  The games are free during your subscription to PSN+.  After that, if you want to keep playing it, you'll have to buy it.

Comment: I don't understand why so many mods closed this as an exact duplicate without even understanding the difference between these questions. I've already explained that this question is about owning content *while the PS Plus subscription is active* (so that any current deals on those games can be availed of).

Comment: @fbueckert - his question is exactly about how to purchase them during this period.

Comment: @www - Welcome! Please review the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) to understand how this site works. While there are appointed moderators, everyone here with enough reputation can [participate in moderation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges). In this case, your question was closed after 5 people with 3000+ rep [voted to close it](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions). The opposite is possible as well. I voted to reopen your question.

Comment: @Gnoupi, thanks for voting to reopen it. Appreciate it, since my reputation is quite low to do that. This is not the first time I've used a stackexchange site, and I'm well aware of what kind of questions are allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that directly off the PlayStation Network Store, since the buy option won't be available for games you own through PS+, only after your subscription has expired will that option be available again.

However, you may be able to purchase the full games through third party sources. For example, [GameStop offers download codes for PSN games](http://www.gamestop.com/browse/games/playstation-3?nav=1351-8d-ffff2418) that can be redeemed on the PSN Store. I assume that if you redeem a code for a game you only "own" through PS+, you'll own it permanently (you can check the game's information in the XMB and see if it has an expiration date).

I cannot confirm this method 100% as I haven't tested it myself, so try at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnoBoy. The GameStop download codes seem to be an alternative to permanently buy the games *while the PS Plus subscription is still active*. Unfortunately, the moderators haven't understood the difference between this question and the other one they've marked this as a duplicate for.

Comment: I, too, feel that this question is different enough. I've voted to reopen it.